# Zend Studio 10 How to use SVN

Tags: php, svn, zend-framework, repository

I am newbie in using SVN so this is my question.
I don't know how SVN really work but I want make new repository like here this were explained:

http://files.zend.com/help/Mobile/Zend-Studio/Advanced/content/configuring_an_svn_connection.htm

I don't know what should be in URL
I paste there path like:
file://F:/wamp/newSVNProject

newSVNProject - is empty folder where I want to make new SVN project

I was installed SVN in Zend Studio in "welcome page" but I don't know what to do next, how create my own SVN repository with the project?  sorry for my english ;-)

I use wamp and I work local

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create your own SVN repository only through the Zend PHP Studio.

What you've installed is the IDE connection to SVN and NOT a SVN server.

You will need to connect to an external (to your IDE/environment) SVN server.
There is a perspective in Eclipse that is used for adding/managing added repositories - it is called "Repository Explorer". You can add a Shortcut to if from the upper right corner of out IDE's window.

If you want to install an Subversion (SVN) Repository you will need to do totally different configurations. The easyest way is to provide the versioned content through a web server - like Apache.

You can [read all about it in the Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html).